# Port-forwarding in router ZTE ZXHN F673AV9

Tags: router, wireless-router, port-forwarding, default-settings

I'm trying to use Remote Play on my PS4 through my phone, but I can only seem to do it if they're on the same wi-fi network (which is pointless).

I tried to look up the problem and it seems my router is blocking the connection. My router has the China Mobile logo on it but when I access the router's settings on the browser it tells me it's the ZTE ZXHN F673AV9.

I was using port-forward.com which has a guide but apparently every router there has a clear "Port-forwarding" section which mine just doesn't have, I don't know if my provider managed to block it somehow, or if it is described differently.

I tried using the "Advanced NAT configuration">"virtual host configuration" tab which gave me a very similar screen to the one shown in the port forwarding tutorial, unfortunately, adding the ports this way didn't work at all.

I tried enabling UPnP which also didn't work and as a desperate attempt tried lowering the firewall to "low" which also didn't work(I set it back to medium afterward).

At this point, I'm running of out options and wanted to know if someone can help me with how to proceed in this situation. I also read somewhere that some routers can't port forward, but if that is the case, how can I enable the connection?